# Which direction is clockwise when rotating around x-axis in 3D?

Tags: matrices, transformation, rotations

[image: picture1 - right hand screw rule]

Picture 1 shows a demonstration that rotations around an axis is positive for clockwise directions.

An example later on, picture 2, applies a rotation matrix for 60 degrees in the x-axis for a clockwise rotation.

[image: picture 2 - worked example]

In the first line of working in picture 2, where

```
Rx(-60) = x_rotation_matrix
```

Am I correct in thinking that the argument for the rotation matrix in the x-axis should be 60 degrees, and not -60 degrees? Additionally, should the argument for the rotation matrix in the y-axis

```
Ry(30) = y_rotation_matrix
```

be -30 degrees, and not 30 degrees?

Thanks.

Comment: It is a matter of perspective.  Traditionally we think of ourselves away from the origin, looking back at the origin, and counter-clockwise turns are positive.  But of we flip the perspective, and imagine the view from the origin, everything is reversed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roughly,It doesn't matter which direction you choose positive.you can choose positive in any direction you wish,but you must have to conduct your all calculations by reminding that in mind.Don't use CW positive in one part of the  calculation and CCW positive in another part. just follow one of them in your full calculation.

But there are some conventional ways for these assumptions.But they vary according to their application.Like,in kinematics generally the convention is "CCW is positive",but When we work on flux measurement in electrical machines like in motor or generator,then it is varied from motor to generator.